# double quote in text to create href doesn't work on vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem to add the href into the Literal control. I spend an hour and didn't work on escape double quot. It shows the text instead of href. Would someone show me how to correct it.

There is my code:

```
dim id as integer=Cint(txtID.text.tostring())
dim href1 as string
Dim href1 As String = "<a target='_blank'  class='body'" & "href='#'"
 href = href & " onclick=""openWin('OrderForm/pop.aspx'?cId=" & id   & "','',500,270);return false;"">" & Link & "</a>" 

Dim ltLink As New Literal
 ltLink.Text = href1
 pnlLink.Controls.Add(ltLink)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, if you want to create markup at server-side, you want to use server control. It is less error prone than creating them manually.

```
Dim id As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.text.tostring())
Dim hyperLink = New HyperLink()
hyperLink.Target = "_blank"
hyperLink.CssClass = "body"
hyperLink.NavigateUrl = "~/OrderForm/pop.aspx?cId=" + id
hyperLink.Text = "Open Window"
hyperLink.Attributes("onclick") = "window.open(this.href, 'targetWindow', 'width=500,height=270');return false;"
pnlLink.Controls.Add(hyperLink)
```

*I don't know what is openWin. I just assume you want to open a new windows. If it is a custom fuction, you can just replace mine with yours.*